# Can't see USB drive connected to Netgear router when selecting a media library for Videostream

Tags: networking, usb, video-streaming

v14.04

I can access it via "Files" as it shows up in the left navigation column so I know it's mounted and working properly, but when I attempt to access it through Videostream, there are no Network connections listed, only locations on the internal HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. you have a USB drive connected to your wireless router. I'm going to go out on a limb and assume it cannot be directly linked to the computer and it contains other folders due to lack of specification. If you can clearly see it on your folder application, try copying and pasting the required files from the USB drive to a location Videostream can see. If this fails to work, try to find a way to directly connect a USB device to your computer.

NOTE: Removing a USB drive from a wireless router does not destroy the data. However, I'm not sure what's on it, so this is my best answer.